# What does probability means in OpenNLP for sentence or name detection?

Tags: opennlp

Trying to make sense of the outcome of API like `SentenceDetecrorEvaluator()`

What do precision mean?

Comment: Using version 1.8.0

Comment: Are you using the API? Can you share some code? I need to make sure what precision you are talking about.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall